# Value Error: invalid literal for int() iwth base 10: '\n' while reading from file

Tags: python

```
def addToEmployee(self):
    id = 1
    name = input('Çalışanın adını giriniz: ')
    surname = input('Çalışanın soyadını giriniz: ')
    age = input('Çalışanın yaşınızı giriniz: ')
    gender = input('Çalışanın cinsiyetini giriniz: ')
    salary = input('Çalışanın maaşını giriniz: ')

    with open('Employee.txt', 'r') as file:
        employeeList = file.readlines()

    if len(employeeList) == 0:
        id = 1
    else:
        with open('Employee.txt', 'r') as file:
            id = int(file.readlines()[-1].split(")")[0]) + 1

    with open('Employee.txt', 'a+') as file:
        file.write("{}){}-{}-{}-{}-{}\n".format(id, name, surname, age, gender, salary))
```

I am a beginner in python. I'm coding a program to improve myself. I want the id number to be increased while adding the records to the file but it doesn't work. I get this error:

id = int(dosya.readlines()[-1].split(")")[0]) + 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Comment: This won't answer why you are getting an error but: Are your ids in order? So does your file look like `1)....\n2)....\n3)...\n`? If yes can't you just do `id = len(employeeList) + 1` instead of reading and incrementing it?

Comment: my file look like 1) .... - .... - .... - .... - .... It can also be done as you say. Thank you for showing a new way.

Answer (score 1):

You created an empty file with a '\n' character. One way to fix it, is to remove existing file and create new one using your program.

```
def addToEmployee():
    id = 1
    name = input('Çalışanın adını giriniz: ')
    surname = input('Çalışanın soyadını giriniz: ')
    age = input('Çalışanın yaşınızı giriniz: ')
    gender = input('Çalışanın cinsiyetini giriniz: ')
    salary = input('Çalışanın maaşını giriniz: ')

    # Notice here we create a new (EMPTY!) file, or does nothing if it already exists
    # Additionally it ensures the file exists
    with open('Employee.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write("")

    with open('Employee.txt', 'r') as file:
        employeeList = file.readlines()

    if len(employeeList) == 0:
        id = 1
    else:
        with open('Employee.txt', 'r') as file:
            id = int(file.readlines()[-1].split(")")[0]) + 1

    with open('Employee.txt', 'a+') as file:
        file.write("{}){}-{}-{}-{}-{}\n".format(id, name, surname, age, gender, salary))
```

Please try to give your questions a better title. This will help future users struggling with your problem find the answer quicker!

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'll be more careful next time. Thank you for your suggestions :)